# How to conditionally set attribute on HTML-element in Meteor.js/Handlebars.js?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

The code below shows one row from a table, and the JavaScript-code to handle the template. The code works, but it sets the disabled-attribute on all the buttons in the table. I only want it for the one button-element that is pushed.

**Question: What is the best way to conditionally set the correct element as disabled in Meteor.js?**

In my HTML-file:

```
<template name="userRow">
<tr>
    <td>{{ username }}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="newRole">
            {{{optionsSelected globalRoles profile.role }}}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        Disabled: {{disabledAttr}}
        {{#isolate}}
            <button type="button" {{disabledAttr}} class="btn btn-xs btn-primary saveUser">Save</button>
        {{/isolate}}
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger deleteUser">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

And in my .js-file:

```
var newUserRole;
var savedDep = new Deps.Dependency;
var saved;
var disabledDep = new Deps.Dependency;
var disabledAttr = "";

Template.userRow.saved = function () {
    savedDep.depend();
    return saved;
};

Template.userRow.disabledAttr = function () {
    disabledDep.depend();
    return disabledAttr;
};

Template.userRow.events({
    'change .newRole' : function (event) {
        newUserRole = event.target.value;
    },

    'click .saveUser' : function (event) {
        disabledAttr = "disabled";
        disabledDep.changed();
        Meteor.call('updateUser',
            {
                userId: this._id,
                role: newUserRole
            },
            function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    saved = "NOT saved, try again!";
                } else {
                    saved = "Saved!";
                    savedDep.changed();
                };
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

All of your rows are using the same Dependency object, so when one row changes the object, all the other rows respond.

To fix this you can create a new Dependency object for each row.

For example:

```
Template.userRow.created = function () {
  this.disabledDep = new Deps.Dependency;
};
```

And update all of your code to use the template's disabledDep instead of the 'global' one.  That should solve your problem.

**But let's talk about your goal here:**

It looks like you want to render your rows differently while saving, until they're confirmed server side.

A cleaner way to do this is to take advantage of Meteor's [isSimulation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) method.  For example:

```
// Put this in a file that will be loaded on both the client and server
Meteor.methods({
  add_item: function (name) {
    Items.insert({name: name,
                  unconfirmed: this.isSimulation});
  }
});
```

This example is using inserts, but you can use the same technique for updates.

Now each document in your collection will have an 'unconfirmed' field, which you can use to change your view:

```
Template.userRow.disabledAttr = function () {
  return this.unconfirmed ? "disabled" : "";
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually went for a different approach, and removed the "Save" button entirely, and just trigger save on change in the select-list, and give the user feedback with FlashMessages on error instead.

Comment: Cool - that's how I do it in my apps too :)